# Не получается разместить React-App приложение на GithubPages

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, github-pages

Пытаюсь разместить React-App приложение на github pages, с помощью данного алгоритма: https://codeburst.io/deploy-react-to-github-pages-to-create-an-amazing-website-42d8b09cd4d

В процессе сборки возникает ошибка, прикладываю логи:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deploy' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~predeploy: filmslist@0.1.0
6 verbose lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~predeploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~predeploy: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\filmslist\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\filmslist\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
8 verbose lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~predeploy: CWD: C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\filmslist
9 silly lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~predeploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]
10 silly lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~predeploy: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~deploy: filmslist@0.1.0
12 verbose lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~deploy: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\filmslist\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\filmslist\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
14 verbose lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\filmslist
15 silly lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gh-pages -d build' ]
16 silly lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle filmslist@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
18 verbose stack Error: filmslist@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
19 verbose pkgid filmslist@0.1.0
20 verbose cwd C:\Users\user\WebstormProjects\filmslist
21 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
23 verbose node v10.16.0
24 verbose npm  v6.9.0
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error filmslist@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the filmslist@0.1.0 deploy script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь в решении этой проблемы

Comment: это ошибка при сборке проекта (`build`)?

Comment: @Август, да но папка build появляется, после сборки осуществляется деплой и возникает ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы не установили ремут ориджин
2. Вы работаете из терминала гита или же через системную консоль? Попробуйте все операции делать через терминал который предоставляет гит

Comment: git remote add origin - с помощью этой команды устанавливается? я сделал это;
Да, системная консоль

Comment: попробовал через gitbash тоже не получилось

Comment: Решил вопрос запуск команды npm run build непосредственно из git bash)